# How to install AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server on Windows 8 Release Preview?

Tags: caching, windows-8, appfabric

How to install AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server on Windows 8 Release Preview? When I try to install it in on Windows 8 Release Preview a get the message

> "WIndows Server AppFabric is not supported on current operating system Windows 8 Release Preview (version 6.2.8400.0). Please refer to installation guide for the list of supported operating systems."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now , AppFabric 1.1 is not supported on the Windows 8 Beta OR Preview. Team will provide guidance about running AppFabric on Windows 8 Server for customers once the final release of Windows 8 is available via their blog and documentations.
Max